# How can I compute the gradient of image function of an noise-less image?

Tags: derivatives, image-processing

I have an $11\times11$ image having in its center a $5\times5$ square, image it's noiseless and I don't know how to compute the intensity of contour for this image. If I remember correctly, I should use a derivative, but I don't know exactly what and how can I use it.

Comment: What is "intensity of contour"?

Comment: @user619894 it's the gradient of the image.

Comment: Maybe you want to compute the "total variation" of this image. Let $x_{ij}$ be the intensity value for pixel $(i,j)$. The total variation is $\sum_{i=1}^{10} \sum_{j=1}^{10} \| \begin{bmatrix} x_{i+1,j} - x_{ij} \\ x_{i,j+1} - x_{ij} \end{bmatrix} \|_2$. You could also use the $\ell_1$-norm rather than the $\ell_2$-norm. Note that we are computing a "discrete gradient vector" at each pixel in the image and then summing up the norns of all these discrete gradient vectors.

Comment: @littleO no, I don't need total variation because, as I've said, the image it's noiseless, so it doesn't contain any noise on it.

Comment: Hmm, my comment also shows how to compute a discrete gradient vector at each pixel location in the image. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: @littleO I think this it's the final step that I need to do, I'm not so familiar with this topic..